# Jsoup select links without hashtags

Tags: java, jsoup

I am filtering links out of a html body using JSOUP.

I use these selectors:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // Select all links
links.select("a[href*=#]").remove(); // remove links containing #
```

But there are still links containing a hashtag. How is this possible?

Comment: When you say "there are still links", do you mean in the Elements (which is a list itself) or in the Document (doc) object?

Comment: in my Elements collection there are links containing "#"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `remove()` method on Elements does not remove the matches from the Elements itself, but rather from the associated Document object.

For example, if you have:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <a href="#someid"></a>
  <a href="http://www.google.pt"></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

after `links.select("a[href*=#]").remove();` you would have:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>  
  <a href="http://www.google.pt"></a>  
 </body>
</html>
```

If you want to select all non-hashtag links you can do this:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href~=[^#]*");
```

Comment: Another way would be:
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.select("a[href*=#]").remove();
   Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");